# Remove only single spaces in text file with sed, perl, awk, tr or anything

Tags: perl, bash, sed, awk, ed

I have a rather large text file where there is an extra space between every character;

```
I t   l o o k s   l i k e   t h i s .
```

I'd like to remove those extra characters so

```
It looks like this.
```

via the Linux terminal.
I can't seem to find anyway to do this without removing all of the whitespaces.  I'm willing to try any solution at this point.  I'd appreciate any nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Are you sure they are spaces and not NUL characters? It sounds like you have something encoded using UTF-16, in which case the solution would be to change the encoding to UTF-8 or whatever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ echo 'I t   l o o k s   l i k e   t h i s .  ' | sed 's/\(.\) /\1/g'
It looks like this.
```

Comment: Awesome.  Just what I needed.  Thanks for the help, also thank you for the very quick response.

Comment: @Jonh : Can you please explain the working of command ? That will be great help..

Answer (score 3):

Are you certain that the intermediate characters are spaces? It is most likely that this is a UTF-16 file.

I suggest you use a capable editor to open it as such and convert it to UTF-8.

Comment: Borodin is right. try to type 'file your_file.txt' to get the encoding. you don't want to corrupt your data right?

Answer (score 3):

An `awk`solution

```
echo "I t   l o o k s   l i k e   t h i s ." | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) printf $i;print ""}' FS=""
It looks like this.
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as it's every other character you want to get rid of, you can use python.

```
>>> s = "I t   l o o k s   l i k e   t h i s ."
>>> print s[0::2]
It looks like this.
```

If you wanted to do this for the text file, do the following:

```
with open("/path/to/file.txt") as f:
    f = f.readlines()

with open("/path/to/new.txt") as g:
    for i in f:
        g.write(str(i)[0::2]+"\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -pe 's|(\s+)| " "x (length($1)>1) |ge' file
```